# Help with Approach to Shell Method

Tags: calculus

I am looking for the volume of the solid by rotating a region R over the Y-axis. The region R is bounded by $y=0$ and $y=4-x^2$ across the interval [0, 2]. The disk method produced the answer $6π$, which should be the correct answer. However, when trying to use the shell method, I used $2π\int_0^2 x(4-x^2-0) \,dx$, which produced the answer $8π$. Can somebody help me understand where the problem in my approach to the shell method is?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please show your calculations for both methods so that readers can detect any errors you may have made.  It looks like your error was with the disk method.

Comment: the correct answer _is_ $8\pi$. Please post how you worked out $6\pi$

Comment: $V=\int_0^4\pi x^2dy=\int_0^4\pi(4-y)dy=8\pi$